# How to use IP in app domain

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app, app, trusted-domain

I have used this tutorial [environment for apps](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236.aspx) to create an app domain. And it's working just fine. 
See below:

[image]

But instead of using domain eg **http://app-754d6678acde5d.myapps.com:4321/**

I want to use ip like **http://app-754d6678acde5d.192.168.9.1:4321/**

Anyone with idea on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

you need to look into dns settings like cname and FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name) for external access obviously.

following should help you:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

as for internally within the network you can add to the host file your own .. below should be ammended where myapps.com lives (your app server)

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

will look something on the lines of:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2006 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
192.168.9.1    myapps.com
```

above allows you to enter the IP address that is pointing to myapps.com

i wouldnt use ip for live server. If this is on dev than changing the host file should be enough.

technically you should already have dns for your app server ;) so really you could just ping yourapp server url in command prompt:

ping myapps.com which should return you the ip of the server. Copy that ip and replace accordingly.

Comment: I have put  192.168.9.1    myapps.com in my local host file.. Buyt when I try to navigate  http://app-754d6678acde5d.192.168.9.1:4321/ I'm getting the error app-754d6678acde5d.192.168.9.1’s server DNS address could not be found.

Comment: i assume http://app-754d6678acde5d.myapps.com:4321/ works? if so you need to get the server ip address for myapps.com. as noted you need to ammend the DNS to accept the ip adress that is just linked to myapps.com. does http://192.168.9.1:4321 work on its own? as that is an internal ip address.